# Calculate coin toss probability for groups of HT

Tags: probability-theory

A biased coin is tossed with probability 0.6 of landing on Heads (H) and probability 0.4 of landing on Tails (T). A run is a maximal sequence of consecutive tosses that land on the same side. For instance, the groups of HTTTHTHTT are (H)(TTT)(H)(T)(H)(TT). I want to calculate:

What is the probability of (strictly) exceeding 6 groups after 10 tosses?

Comment: Is this question from the book "Introduction to Probability" by Charles Grindstead? I recall a similar question from that book except I don't know if it's the same.

Comment: Yes, but it does not answer the question im trying to answer above

Comment: Hold on let me pull up my book. Grinstead had this as one of his examples.

Comment: Any luck? I am not sure if my part of the question is in the book as it only gives the expected value. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I have nothing at the moment. I will write back when I have a clear explanation for your question.